# Navigation Bar Style change in *AppDelegate.m

Tags: iphone, three20

Im using three20 framework and trying to change the top naivagation bar from the standard to UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque.

I tried using many things in many places but it does not seem to work :/

I tried in my main *appdelegate.m and then in a another "page1.m"

I've used the below in the appdelegate.m

```
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
navigator.rootViewController.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

I've used the below in the page1.m

```
self.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque; // This works! but the below doesnt
self.navigationBarStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
self.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT

Also tried the following and still did not work

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.navigationBarStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

and

```
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navigator.rootViewController.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

/EDIT2

Debugging did not give me my results, in my .m file, this is how its called

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    self.title = @"MyTitle";
NSLog(self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title);//DIDNT WORK
NSLog(self.navigationItem.title);//Worked
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

should be:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

//EDIT: for debugging purposes you can log all

```
*.navigationBar.topItem.title
```

and see if it prints out your current title. If not, its the wrong navigation controller.

Comment: and the same in your AppDelegate ;)

Comment: Tried this, Still didn't work :(, edited top post to reflect this. Thanks for the help though

Comment: even for self.navigationBarStyle ?

Comment: Yes, I've added what i've got at the top to reflect this. Maybe im doing something wrong still

Comment: you can test every combination that could be possible even if the navigation bar is named differently. but it should be the topItem of a navigationBar, not the topItem of the controller or subitem

Comment: Your Right, Its not giving me my title when self.title gives me my title but the others dont!

     NSLog(self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title);//Doesnt Give title     

NSLog(self.navigationItem.title);//Gives Title     

Maybe this helps? This is how its Done     

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {     
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {     
  self.title = @"MyTltle";

Comment: If you have a nib File then you can connect your navigationBar and then access this class variable

Comment: No Nib file, do not use the IB :/, is there a way to find out what the navigationbar is called on three20's framework?

Comment: yes sure, I don't use the framework but as far as I know you have the full source code, so you have to open the source file you using and find out how it's named, sorry that I cannot say more, but I don't use it :D

Answer (score 0):

`UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` is a constant to style the *status bar*, which is the black or grey thing on the top of your screen, showing time, reception, battery charge etc.

You change it using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:...]
```

as for changing a *navigation* bar, try the things you listed one by one, and make sure to do it not too early, i.e. not before the view controller has been loaded and initialized.

A good place for these things is in your view controllers `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks, I the statusbar changes, bit the navigation bar doesnt change. I'm 100% sure i've loaded it as the last thing (even after it sets the title for the nav bar) and still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This may be what your looking for... (make sure you change the tint color):

```
CGFloat version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
//NSLog(@"version %f", version);
if (version <= 6.1) {
    //NSLog(@"setting navbar style to black");
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```